# How can I take a 'Slice' out of a 3D model using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, 3d

Subject line may not be the best description of what I'm trying to do.

Basically I want to take a 3D model of a group of buildings and either remove all points above a certain elevation, or preferably take a 'slice' by eliminating all points above and below a certain min and max elevation.

I just started using QGIS in conjunction with Agisoft Photoscan I know I would be left with no images of the tops of the buildings.  Essentially what is going on is many buildings have large roof overhangs or ground features (doorsteps, etc).  I want to estimate the dimensions of the buildings taken like 5 feet off the ground to effectively disregard the roof overhangs and the protruding features from the ground up to 5 feet.

Is this something I can do in QGIS?  If so, what type of file format would be best to import into QGIS for this purpose and what's the basic workflow?